# PHP - how to get info from more than 1 row after query? Only getting first row?

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, Im new to PHP and have set up a basic PM system.  In a div, I am trying to display users that the user signed in has started a conversation with, meaning a row exists in my conversation table with user_one being the signed in user's id and user_two the other user's id.

I have managed to get the number of conversations the user has open and the id of user_two of the FIRST CONVERSATION listed in the data base here:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","sqlserver");

                    //$num = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `pm_messages` WHERE user_from=".$account['id']."");
                $numCon = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `conversation` WHERE user_one=".$account['id']."");
                    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($numCon);
                $u =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($numCon);

                    for($i=0; $i<$numrows; $i++)
                    {
                        //echo "<a href='message.php?id={$row['id']}'><li> $i</li></a>";
                        echo $u['user_two'];
                    }
```

Then attempted to use a for loop to echo out links to all the users with which the user has a conversation open, but I do not know how to "move through the rows", so to speak.

```
echo $u['user_two'];
```

The above just echoes the first user_two 3 times since there are 3 conversations. How can I get the other 2 user ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `fetch` inside the loop. Each time you call `fetch` it retrieves the *next* row, and after you've read the last row the next call to `fetch` returns **`null`**. The usual idiom is to use `fetch` to condition a `while` loop, like this:

```
while ($u = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numCon))
{
    //echo "<a href='message.php?id={$row['id']}'><li> $i</li></a>";
    echo $u['user_two'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

loop it using while() 
try this :

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","sqlserver");

                //$num = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `pm_messages` WHERE user_from=".$account['id']."");
            $numCon = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `conversation` WHERE user_one=".$account['id']."");
                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($numCon);
           while($u =  mysqli_fetch_array($numCon))


                {
                    //echo "<a href='message.php?id={$row['id']}'><li> $i</li></a>";
                    echo $u['user_two'];
                }
```